# Spring security authentication management vulnerability

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

Spring documentation says that remember me is implemented by storing following information in cookie -

> base64(username + ":" + expirationTime + ":" + md5Hex(username + ":" +
>   expirationTime + ":" password + ":" + key))

I have following confusions -

1. Why use an unsecure hash like MD5 to digest the information instead of using SHA-1 or SHA-2. Would the performance hit from these be significant for such a small piece of information?
2. Why transmit this information over the network at all? Why not maintain a map of cryptographically secure random number and this info on the server, returning only the map key as a cookie. AFAIK this is the approach used by Servlet API and is deemed more secure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets begin with the second question because it is the more relevant one:

**second question** "Why transmit the password over the network at all...." answer:

Because what you described is only the `Simple Hash-Based Token Approach`

If you scroll down the page [Spring Security Reference: Chapter 10 Remember-Me Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) you will see that spring security can also use a different remember me approaches: [Chapter 10.3 Persistent Token Approach](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html). And this is what you suggested in your second question.

---

**first question**: Short answer to "Would the performance hit from these be significant for such a small piece of information?" - No

So if you want to use the `Simple Hash-Based Token Approach` and feel that MD5 is to unsecured, then you can subclass `TokenBasedRememberMeService` [[javadoc]](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html) and override the `String makeTokenSignature(long tokenExpiryTime, String username, String password)` method. For example (untested)

```
protected String makeTokenSignature(long tokenExpiryTime, String username, String password) {
    String data = username + ":" + tokenExpiryTime + ":" + password + ":" + getKey();
    MessageDigest digest;
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No SHA-256 algorithm available!");
    }

    return new String(Hex.encode(digest.digest(data.getBytes())));
}
```

Comment: Overriding makeTokenSignature() looks like a good way to go, as I don't think SHA-2 can be broken. I wonder in what case would one need to use a persistent token approach at all.

Comment: Because the persistence approach is much more secure at all. Providing no information about the password is always better then sending an encrypted password. -- But this discussion tend to be theoretical. -- Anyway I prefer the persistent token approach, because this enables additional features like deleting such an token.

Comment: The persistent token approach is definitely better but I'm not sure what is insecure about using MD5 in this scenario, where it's basically being used as a signature.   You would need access to both the hashed password and the key the reproduce the MD5 hash.

Comment: @ericacm: think the problem is not to reproduce the token, the problem is that somebody could "recalculate" the password from the token.

Comment: I am not sure how that would be possible.

Comment: @ericacm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 -- in general if it is no problem then one should use a more secure algorithm. *(On the other hand, no one will spend the needed amount time and money on hacking some MD5 cookie for a website if he can corrupt the cleaning lady for much less.)*

Comment: See my answer below.  Here is a gut check: The simple hash remember me feature has been a part of Spring Security (Acegi) since at least 2005 if not from the very beginning.  Don't you think that if the MD5 hash was a problem that it would have been called out and fixed a long time ago?

Comment: @ericacm: I dont want to justify if the MD5 approach is critical vulnerability (*I dont think that it is if you salt it*). I only want to answer the question. 1) performance - No, 2) this is implemented too.

Comment: @ericacm I agree with Ralph on this. The problem is that somebody could recalculate the password. Correct me if I'm wrong, but due to collision vulnerabilities in MD5, computational complexity for a brute force is low. If the attacker registers an account on the site he knows every component of the hash except the salt, for which he can run a brute force. Once the salt gets compromised every user account could be at risk.

Comment: @Kshitiz Sharma: the effort you need to recalcualte is quite high, to high for a simple web site, may not high enoght for a banking site. -- Use the stored token approach and this discussion is over.

Answer (score 5):

The MD5 hash used by the Simple Hash-Based token is not a vulnerability of that approach.

Using MD5 to hash passwords is dangerous because, given the hashed value of an existing password, you can find another password that hashes to the same value (using a rainbow table).

However, in this case MD5 is not being used to hash passwords but is being used as a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).  If you did use a rainbow table to find a value that collides with that hash, how exactly could you use that value?

Using a different hash function for the cookie may make you feel more secure but it's not providing any more security in this case.

If you want more security then you should use the Persistent Hash token approach.  The Simple Hash Token exposes the username in cleartext and is vulnerable to replay attacks.   The Persistent Token avoids these problems.

Either way you should secure your remember-me cookie by setting its Secure and Http-only flag.

Comment: (+1) for clear explain the pros of Persistent Hash token approach - even it this was only a question from the comments